# How to upgrade google cardboard sdk for unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm creating simple vr game and I use spatial audio in it. Recently 0.7 version of cardboard sdk for unity came out and I want to upgrade my 0.6 version because they added audio mixers for spatial audio. I'm new to unity so I'm probably doing somtehing wrong. I just tried importing new package but I've got this error while I was  trying to import it: 
[image: error1]
(odmowa dotępu means access denied)
Then when I click cancel I get these bugs:
[image: error2]

Do you know how should I upgrade this package correctly? I haven't done anything like this before so I might have done it completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

On GVR's page it is suggested to open an empty scene and delete the GoogleVR and Plugins folders before importing the new version:
https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/release-notes#upgrade_instructions

In GVR 1.30 I still get this error. Although I delete all previous files of the package (Both GoogleVR and Plugins folders) I still get the same error but clicking cancel completes the installation without any errors. I can also find the problem file audioplugingvrunity.dll in x86_64 folder.

I don't know how it can happen but maybe the package installer is trying to write the same file more than once.